# HTML5/Javascript Image loading method & passing to variable

Tags: javascript, html, image, load

I have some code for loading images.

```
var assets = {
    total:0,
    success:0,
    error:0
};
var stillLoading = true;
var img = {};

function LoadImage(name, path){
    var toLoad = new Image();
    toLoad.src = path;
    assets.total++;
    toLoad.addEventListener("load", function(){
        assets.success++;
        console.log(name + " loaded.");
        img[name] = toLoad;
    }, false);
    toLoad.addEventListener("error", function(){
        assets.error++;
    }, false);
};

function Loading(){
    if (assets.success == assets.total){
        if (stillLoading){
            console.log("All assets loaded. Starting game.");
        };
        stillLoading = false;
        return false;
    }else{  
        stillLoading = true;
        return true;
    };
};
```

May still be inefficient, and ugly since I'm new to practicing javascript, open to suggestions. It loads the image and tells the main program when all the assets have finished loading through the function Loading(), and then adds the image to the object img.

I've been using this for a while now for my images, and it works.

For example, if I did.

```
LoadImage("Car", "imageOfCar.png");
ctx.drawImage(img.Car, 0, 0);
```

this would draw the image just fine to the canvas.

However, when I assign another variable the image, which for various reasons I want to do, such as assigning images to objects. e.g.

```
var secondCar = img.Car
```

then try to draw it.

```
ctx.drawImage(secondCar, 0, 0);
```

I get this error.

**Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(HTMLImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap)'**

If it works for the initial variable, it should act the same way towards another variable that has just been assigned the exact same thing. So why is it am I getting this error?

If I was to load the image the typical way that doesn't check if it's finished loading.

```
img.Car = new Image();
img.Car.src = "imageOfCar.png";
secondCar = img.Car;
ctx.drawImage(secondCar);
```

This would work.
The behaviour here is a bit confusing, could someone explain to me what is happening, and perhaps suggest a way to fix it?

EDIT: Just to clarify.

This is the html file, called index.html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>HTML5 Game Base</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="screen" width="270" height="480" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
    <script src = "script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The canvas is set up as `screen`. All the javascript code I've displayed above takes place within script.js which is called in index.html.

This is how `screen` is called within the script.js.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("screen");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
```

This is what `ctx.drawImage()` is referencing.

Comment: Where is `ctx` variable defined?

Comment: Ah, that's something I forgot to clarify. I've set up the canvas in a html file. The html file then calls a javascript file, which calls the canvas as `ctx`. All the code I'm showing here takes place within the javascript file, I've made a few implications, so if there's anything else, just ask.

Comment: _The html file then calls a javascript file, which calls the canvas as ctx._ So show the relevant code.

Comment: Done that, take another look please. Thanks.

Comment: _"However, when I assign another variable the image, which for various reasons I want to do, such as assigning images to objects. e.g. `var secondCar = img.Car`"_ Is `secondCar` defined after `LoadImage` is called ? Can you create a stacksnippets or jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate error message ?

Comment: Have the image finished loading before you try to draw it?

Comment: Sure, here. https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=fBRHRhPnxb

Comment: And yep, I have checked using console messages. It only attempts to draw after all the images are loaded. Hopefully it is actually checking that they're loaded, as from my understanding the event listeners I have should do the job. If I've done something wrong I'd like to know.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this won't be the most helpful answer, but I tinkered around with your code a little. This is what I used:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>HTML5 Game Base</title>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="screen" width="270" height="480" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
    <script>
    var stillLoading = true;
    var img = {};
    var canvas = document.getElementById("screen");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    assets = {};
    assets.total = 0;

    function LoadImage(name, path){
        var toLoad = new Image();
        toLoad.src = path;
        assets.total++;
        toLoad.addEventListener("load", function(){
            //assets.success++;
            console.log(name + " loaded.");
            img[name] = toLoad;
        }, false);
        toLoad.addEventListener("error", function(){
            assets.error++;
        }, false);
    }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Then in Chrome's console I typed

```
LoadImage("Car", "map.png");
LoadImage("un", "Untitled.png");
ctx.drawImage(img.Car, 0, 0);
ctx.drawImage(img.un, 0, 0);
```

and get the expected result of images loading in the canvas. Even when assigning one of the `img` images to a new variable, this works as expected.

```
var second = img.Car
ctx.drawImage(second, 0, 0)
```

It appears everything is working fine when run manually, so my guess would be timing. When are you running these commands? Are they in the js file or from the console?

It would appear your LoadImage function is fine. Sorry this is not super helpful, but hopefully will help you rule out where not to look for the problem.

Comment: I'm running them from within the js file. I'm using my Loading() function to make sure any code that will use the assets will only run after all the images are loaded, seems you'e gotten rid of that.

Comment: I did because I was just running it from the console. Definitely sounds like a timing issue. Basically the image is not ready when you try to load it. This is one of the usual pains with JS. The answer below me talks about promises and that's the way to go. They can be difficult to wrap your head around at first but well worth the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be to utilize `Promise` , as `load` event of `new Image` is asynchronous `secondCar` could be `undefined` when used as parameter within `setInterval`, e.g., `load` event of `img` may not be complete when `var secondCar = img.Car` applied after call to `LoadImage`; also added variable reference for `setInterval` for ability to call `clearInterval()` if needed

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("screen");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var interval = null;

var assets = {
  total: 0,
  success: 0,
  error: 0
};
var stillLoading = true;
var img = {};

function LoadImage(name, path) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var toLoad = new Image();
    assets.total++;
    toLoad.addEventListener("load", function() {
      assets.success++;
      console.log(name + " loaded.");
      img[name] = toLoad;
      // resolve `img` , `assets` object
      resolve([img, assets])
    }, false);
    toLoad.addEventListener("error", function() {
      assets.error++;
      reject(assets)
    }, false);
    toLoad.src = path;
  })
};

function Loading() {
  if (assets.success == assets.total) {
    if (stillLoading) {
      console.log("All assets loaded. Starting game.");
    };
    stillLoading = false;
    return false;
  } else {
    stillLoading = true;
    return true;
  };
};

var promise = LoadImage("Car", "http://pngimg.com/upload/audi_PNG1736.png");
promise.then(function(data) {
  // `data` : array containing `img` , `assets` objects
  console.log(data);
  var secondCar = data[0].Car;
  interval = setInterval(function() {
    if (!(Loading())) {
      ctx.drawImage(secondCar, 0, 0);
    };
  }, 1000 / 60);
});
```

```html
<canvas id="screen" width="1000" height="700" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Turns out it was a timing issue. In the example I gave, when `secondCar` is assigned `img.Car`, `img.Car` had not yet loaded.

Instead I created a new function called `Initialise()`, and called it from within `Loading()`. So from now on I would just have to initialise all my variables that may require images from within `Initialise()`. This way, variables can only be assigned images after they've loaded.

New Code:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("screen");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var assets = {
    total:0,
    success:0,
    error:0
};
var stillLoading = true;
var img = {};

function LoadImage(name, path){
    var toLoad = new Image();
    toLoad.src = path;
    assets.total++;
    toLoad.addEventListener("load", function(){
        assets.success++;
        console.log(name + " loaded.");
        img[name] = toLoad;
    }, false);
    toLoad.addEventListener("error", function(){
        assets.error++;
    }, false);
};

function Loading(){
    if (assets.success == assets.total){
        if (stillLoading){
            console.log("All assets loaded. Starting game.");
            Initialise();
        };
        stillLoading = false;
        return false;
    }else{  
        stillLoading = true;
        return true;
    };
};

LoadImage("Car", "http://pngimg.com/upload/audi_PNG1736.png");

function Initialise(){
    window.secondCar = img.Car;
};



setInterval(function(){
    if (!(Loading())) ctx.drawImage(secondCar, 0, 0);
}, 1000/60);
```

Works now, thanks for the help although I ended up solving it myself. I would still appreciate any tips on how to improve it. Or knowing that I'm new to javascript, any nitpicks to help me conform to javascript conventions.